# How to share array(list)/variables between tabbed pane in Java swing?

Tags: java, swing, parameter-passing

I been trying to do "the question title". Here is my current code:

Main.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

JFrame f= new JFrame ("My Frame");
f.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame .EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

JTabbedPane tp = new JTabbedPane();
User user = new User();
tp.addTab("Register", new Register(user));
tp.addTab("Process", new Process(user));

f.add(tp);
f.pack();
f.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Register.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Register extends JPanel {
/*
    The code too long, but what this class does is, display textfields:
    username, password and email address
    And there is a submit button, when press, it will update the process pane
    */
}
```

How to pass the username password and email to Process.java(Jpanel)?

[I am new to java and no programming background]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I can see, you share `user` between `Register` and `Process`. So the problem is how to refresh `Process` when data in `user` are updated. You could create listener on `User`, or on 'Register'. IMHO listener on 'Register' is more elegant.

RegisterListener:

```
public interface RegisterListener {
  void userRegistered(User user);
}
```

Register:

```
public void addRegisterListener(RegisterListener listener) {
  //add listener to some collection.
}

//Call this method on Submit button press
protected void fireRegistered() {
  //iterate over collection of listeners and on each do:
    listener.userRegistered(user);
}
```

Process:

```
Process implements RegisterListener {
  public void userRegistered(User user) {
    refreshView();
  }
}
```

And in main:

```
Register register = new Register(user);
Process process = new Process();
register.addRegisterListener(process);
```

So Process should be informed when user is registered, and it should receive all the necessary data in `user` parameter of listener method.

Comment: RegisterListener is 1 file, Register is another file? Thanks for the answer, I will give it a try, and will update the result in few minutes

Comment: Its very confusing, so where do I add the pane? SOrry, if I am too stupid

Comment: In Java, every class or interface has to be in separate file. Except when we make inner class or interface, but this is not the case here.

What pane don't you know where to add? JTabbedPane? Nothing changed here, add it to JFrame like before.